# Issue with threads in C

Tags: c, syntax-error

I'm getting an error from my program, which is still a work in progress, and the error is confusing me. The program is one that uses threads to speed up the calculations of the sum of square roots in a number divisible by four. My code is as follows.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define NUM_THREADS 3;
int ARGV;
pthread_mutex_t m = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
int total;


void *calc(int t){
int ttl;
int i;
if (t == 0) {
    for (i == ((ARGV / 4) + 1); i < (ARGV / 2); i++){
        ttl = ttl + sqrt(i);
    }
} else if (t == 1) {
    for (i == ((ARGV / 2) + 1); i < ((3 * ARGV) / 4); i++){
        ttl = ttl + sqrt(i);
    }
} else if (t == 2) {
    for (i == (((3 * ARGV) + 1) / 4); i < ARGV; i++){
        ttl = ttl + sqrt(i);
    }
}
pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
total = total + ttl;
pthread_mutex_unlock;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int i;
    int ttl;
    ARGV =  atoi(argv[1]);

    pthread_t ti[NUM_THREADS];

    for (i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) {
        pthread_create(&ti[i], NULL, calc, i);
    }
    for (i == 1; i < (ARGV / 4) ; i++){
            ttl = ttl + sqrt(i);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++)   {
        pthread_join(&ti[i], NULL);
    }
    total = total + ttl;
}
```

The error I'm getting is thr.c:37: error: expected ']' before ';' token, which I don't understand, because the symbol that is expected is there. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This line looks wrong: `for (i == ((ARGV / 4) + 1); i < (ARGV / 2); i++)`.   `==` is used to *test* a value.  Typically, the first statement in a for-loop *assigns* a value, as in:  `i = ARGV/4+1;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#define NUM_THREADS 3;
```

So:

```
pthread_t ti[NUM_THREADS];
```

Expands to:

```
pthread_t ti[3;];
```

The `]` should be *before* the `;`, as the error says.

Comment: Thanks for that, I see it now. Guess that's what I get for attempting to rush things.

Answer (score 4):

You should have

```
#define NUM_THREADS 3
```

instead of

```
#define NUM_THREADS 3;
```

No `;` at the end.

That is because the substitution is done textually so `thread_t ti[NUM_THREADS];` gets expanded as `thread_t ti[3;];` and from here you get the error.

Hint: When macros are involved in the error you can compile with `-E` and look at the expansions for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Do not put semi-colons at the end of your `#define` statements.

It should be

```
#define NUM_THREADS 3
```

---

All your for loops look wrong:

```
for (i == ((ARGV / 4) + 1); i < (ARGV / 2); i++)
```

the double-equal (`==`) is used to test a value.
So `i == ((ARGV/4) + 1);` will be true-or-false, depending on the value of i.

Typically, the first statement in a for-loop *assigns* a value, as in:

```
for (i = ARGV/4 + 1; i < (ARGV / 2); i++)
```

(unless you actually mean to test the value of `i`? for reasons that are not clear)

Comment: Doesn't solve the compilation problem he has; is not an helpful answer to his question.

Comment: Thanks for this as well, while it's not the exact issue I was having, it is a helpful comment. Once again, me rushing is a bad thing.